# usage of 은/는 and 이/가

Tags: grammar, particle

In one of my lessons, in response to asking if they had an umbrella they responded "우산 없어요." They asked "그럼 이것은요?" I don't understand why they used 은 instead of 이 or an object particle.

Comment: In short, you have to use 은/는 when you change the topic.